# CRM 2011 Custom SQL based report error after change default filters

Tags: sql, filter, report, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have some report in SQL (with pre-filtering). 
I import this report to CRM (Dynamics CRM 2011) and run - everything is ok.

But when I changed default filter for this report in CRM and save - report is not run anymore (report error).
I download and checked this two files (before change default filters and after change that) and problem is that when I changed filters, crm insert into link-entity (xml 'join' node) some alias which is GUID. When I change this alias (in rdl file) from GUID to 'ab' for example and reimport this report to CRM, it is work again - until someone change default filter...

So what I shold to do ? Because now it is impossible to give users possibility to change default filter for report in CRM.

edit:
Mostly whole xml for .rdl file is the same for both reports. Only difference is in CustomProperty node. In this node is definition for defualt filter.

Section from work report width default filters without any changes:

```
<CustomProperty>
<Name>Custom</Name>
<Value>
<MSCRM xmlns="mscrm">
<ReportFilter>
<ReportEntity paramname="P1">
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
<entity name="sc_accountevents">
<all-attributes />
<filter type="and">
<condition attribute="modifiedon" operator="last-x-days" value="30" />
</filter>
</entity>
</fetch>
</ReportEntity>
<ReportEntity paramname="P2">
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
<entity name="businessunit">
<all-attributes />
<filter type="and">
<condition attribute="modifiedon" operator="last-x-days" value="30" />
</filter>
</entity>
</fetch>
</ReportEntity>
<ReportEntity paramname="P3">
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
<entity name="account">
<all-attributes />
<filter type="and">
<condition attribute="modifiedon" operator="last-x-days" value="30" />
</filter>
</entity>
</fetch>
</ReportEntity>
</ReportFilter>
</MSCRM>
</Value>
</CustomProperty>
```

Section from broken report (after change default filters):

```
<CustomProperty>
<Name>Custom</Name>
<Value>
<MSCRM xmlns="mscrm">
<ReportFilter>
<ReportEntity paramname="P1" displayname="Account Events">
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
<entity name="sc_accountevents">
<all-attributes />
<link-entity name="account" from="accountid" to="sc_klientid" visible="false" link-type="outer" alias="a_58cc568ca7ece311896000155d68d9dc">
<attribute name="sc_jednostkabiznesowaid"/>
</link-entity>
<link-entity name="systemuser" from="systemuserid" to="owninguser" alias="ae">
<filter type="and">
<condition attribute="businessunitid" operator="eq-businessid"/>
</filter>
</link-entity>
</entity>
</fetch>
</ReportEntity>
<ReportEntity paramname="P2" displayname="Jednostki biznesowe">
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
<entity name="businessunit">
<all-attributes />
</entity>
</fetch>
</ReportEntity>
<ReportEntity paramname="P3" displayname="Klienci">
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
<entity name="account">
<all-attributes />
</entity>
</fetch>
</ReportEntity>
</ReportFilter>
</MSCRM>
</Value>
</CustomProperty>
```

And again work report with changed default filters but with edit alias in link-entity node:

```
<CustomProperty>
<Name>Custom</Name>
<Value>
<MSCRM xmlns="mscrm">
<ReportFilter>
<ReportEntity paramname="P1" displayname="Account Events">
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
<entity name="sc_accountevents">
<all-attributes />
<link-entity name="account" from="accountid" to="sc_klientid" visible="false" link-type="outer" alias="ab">
<attribute name="sc_jednostkabiznesowaid"/>
</link-entity>
<link-entity name="systemuser" from="systemuserid" to="owninguser" alias="ae">
<filter type="and">
<condition attribute="businessunitid" operator="eq-businessid"/>
</filter>
</link-entity>
</entity>
</fetch>
</ReportEntity>
<ReportEntity paramname="P2" displayname="Jednostki biznesowe">
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
<entity name="businessunit">
<all-attributes />
</entity>
</fetch>
</ReportEntity>
<ReportEntity paramname="P3" displayname="Klienci">
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
<entity name="account">
<all-attributes />
</entity>
</fetch>
</ReportEntity>
</ReportFilter>
</MSCRM>
</Value>
</CustomProperty>
```

Comment: Can you post the query before and after you change the default filter ?

Comment: I added queries to first post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. 
Probably no way to do something with this.

It's a bug which is remove in rollup 17 (2 months ago)...